# Regex Issue for multiple format in a log

Tags: regex, fluent

I have a apache log with 2 different formats and use below config for td-agent.
With this config,only one log matches and other one says pattern not match.
Can some help tweaking this regex to match both scenarios?

```
@type tail
path           /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
pos_file       /var/log/td-agent/var_log_httpd_ssl_access_log.pos
read_from_head true
tag            /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
<parse>
  @type regexp
    expression  /^(?<client_ip>[^ ]*)((, [^ ]*)*)? (?<proxy_ip>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) (?<time>[^ ]*) "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) (?<protocol>[A-Z]{1,}[^ ]*)+\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) (?<duration>[^ ]*) (?<received>[^ ]*) (?<sent>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)?" "(?<user_agent>[^\"]*)?")?(?: (?<userid>[^ ]*))?/
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z
</parse>
```

`10.40.2.100 - - 2020-03-02T14:18:06.688+0000 "-" 408 - 18 423 137` (pattern does not match)

`156.99.165.40, 10.40.2.100 10.40.2.100 - - 2020-03-02T14:18:06.710+0000 "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 500 336 1769 1431 725 "https://app.tl.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"` - (Works fine).

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Can you please mention clearly what your sample input and desired outputs are? Also, what all can a log contain?

Comment: What do you want to match? 2 different formats of what? Please be clear.